# Unable to retrieve all the data in chunks using Observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I am attempting to use a streaming strategy to send data in chunks to the browser. However, when the data is read it does not send them in chunks from the code written to stream the results. It reads and sends the first batch and then gives a message that there are some more items left. Why isn't the rest of the data streamed? I thought was how Observables work, to read the data in chunks in the next callback. Here are how the results are displayed, but with the ... more items, shown below

```
               [ 
                   ...,
                   {
                    productCode: 1829222,
                    productName: 'Twizzlers'
                 
                   } ,
                   ... 141 more items
               ]
```

Here is the code that tries to stream the data:

```js
        const fetch = (url, payload) =>{
        try{
           const requestOptions = {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
              body: JSON.stringify(payload),
            };
            const request = new Request(url, requestOptions);
            const data$ = fromFetch(request).pipe(
              switchMap(response => {
                 if (response.ok) {
                   return response.json();
                 } else {
                   return of({ error: true, message: `Error ${ response.status }` });
                 }
               }),
               catchError(err => {
                 console.error(err);
                 return of({ error: true, message: err.message })
               })
            );
             data$.subscribe({
                 next: result => console.log(result),
                 complete: () => console.log('done')
              });
            }catch(e){
              console.error(e) 
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am attempting to use a streaming strategy to send data in chunks to the browser.

Data *is* sent to the browser in chunks. When the server sends data to the browser, the server is sending it in "chunks" and the browser is storing it in a buffer. You are decoding that buffer to something useable when you run `response.json()`.

For further reading on TCP connections (How GET, POST, etc) work under the hood, I suggest reading the "Bulding blocks of TCP" chapter in the book "High Performance Browser Networking" https://hpbn.co/building-blocks-of-tcp/

**Your code works well with standard GET request for some dummy json**. I can see the response well and I'm not seeing the error you are seeing
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-xwyctu?file=index.ts

If you are actually trying to "stream" data to the browser, you can look into Server Sent Events (SSE) https://hpbn.co/server-sent-events-sse/. This is how you can establish a long running GET request to stream data from the server to the client.

You can see an example here: https://github.com/Fallenstedt/server-sent-events-example

Comment: I am not seeing an error, what I am seeing is that not all the chunked data is logged, I see only part of it logged and then I see .... more items and the complete callback is called. It does not make sense to me that complete is called when there are still more items to log

Comment: I don't get an error, the console.log just doesn't print all the data as it emits ...more items 114 items. I expected to see the first 100 items followed by the 114 items